# Register Firebase Listener Without Calling It?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to register a Firebase listener function without calling it when you register it?

For example:

```
this.gamestateURL.on('value', function(snapshot){
    self.GameStateChangeEvent(snapshot);
});
```

GameStateChangeEvent function fires immediately upon setting up the listener.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on) specifically state:

> This event will trigger once with the initial data stored at this location, and then trigger again each time the data changes. The DataSnapshot passed to the callback will be for the location at which on() was called. It won't trigger until the entire contents has been synchronized. If the location has no data, it will be triggered with an empty DataSnapshot (val() will return null).

You could, however do something like this:

```
var ref = this.gamestateURL // or however you create a ref

function doSomethingWithAddedOrChangedSnapshot(snapshot) {
     // this function is called whenever a child is added
     // or changed
}

// assuming you have "timestamp" property on these objects
// it will not be called back with any snapshots on initialization
// because the timestamp of existing snapshots will not be greater
// than the current time
ref.orderByChild('timestamp')
   .startAt(new Date().getTime())
   .on('child_added', doSomethingWithAddedOrChangedSnapshot);

ref.on('child_changed', doSomethingWithAddedOrChangedSnapshot);

ref.once('value', function(snapshot){
    // get the initial state once
    // this snapshot represents all the items on this ref
    // this will only fire once on initialization
    initializeGameData(snapshot.val());
});
```

In English:

- Create one function that handles the updated/added child
- start listening to the `child_added` event for all children added after the current timestamp (unix time since epoch). This also assumes you're storing the timestamp on these children.
- start listening to the `child_changed` event for any child that is changed.
- grab all the values of the ref once to initialize your data.
- not sure if your use case needs to handle 'child_removed' or 'child_moved'